Java Escape Sequence with Apostrophe
I have a .eml file with the html content of an email inside it, as well as email headers.
I would like to form a dynamic css selector which will select elements inside the email body based on the user's email. Here is code which creates html document, and selects matching element.
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlBody); 
Element targetElement = document.selectFirst(
         findExactReplyMatchQueriesStream(emails)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) 
); 

Let's assume this method builds my selector:
private Stream<String> findExactReplyMatchQueriesStream(Set<String> emails) { 
    return emails.stream()
                 .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty) 
                 .map(recipient -> String.format(":matches(%s)", 
                                                 String.format("^%s$", Pattern.quote(recipient))));
}

Note the Pattern.quote() which is being used in case there are special characters inside the email.
Ok, so for regular emails this works fine. For example, for email list "john@gmail.com", "clara@gmail.com" I get the elements as expected.
The problem starts when my emails get more complicated. Specifically, when there's an apostrophe in them. So, for example if my list contains "john1'123@gmail.com", "clara's@gmail.com", I receive this error:
org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Unmatched closing ')' near index 21
^\Qclara's@gmail.com\E$),:matches(^\Qjohn1'123@gmail.com\E$
                     ^

I know what the problem is - the apostrophe is not working together with the escape sequence. I know that I could potentially remove the \Q\E sequence before these emails and it would work for these cases but I want a broader solution that would work for all special characters, and that would also work for an apostrophe. Does anyone have any workarounds for this?
Just to confirm, the same exact code works perfectly with "john@gmail.com", "clara@gmail.com". Also, these are perfectly valid emails (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address for more information)

The error says you have an unmatched closing paren which has nothing to do with quoting and nothing to do with single quotes. You.. simply forgot an open paren.

Note that your code looks a bit weird like this. Don't nest format calls, just make that String.format(":matches(^%s$)", Pattern.quote(recipient)).
